# Document iteration: what problems should I account for?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
(function( d, w ){

    function showClimb( e ){
        var t = e.target;
        console.log( t.id );
        while( t.id !== 'document-body' ){
            t = t.parentNode;
            console.log( t.id );
        }
    }

    d.body.addEventListener( 'click', showClimb, false );

}( document, window ))
```

I just wrote this snippet to test if an element or it's child has been selected. What risks does this approach have? What failsaves should I include to make sure this loop doesn't get stuck somehow? I am writing for IE9 and higher.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! For clarity, are you only targeting IE as a browser and don't care about others?

Comment: Thank you!, I care about ie, safari, chrome, android browser, mobile safari, firefox and firefox mobile. Only ie 7 and 8 are dropped,

Answer (score 1):

Well, overall, I'd worry first about your variable names :D `d`, `w` and `t` especially. A dev coming in seeing this would say "what sorcery is this?".

Now `t.id` isn't a guarantee. Not all elements may have an `id` attribute. You might encounter blanks while climbing up. Try filling it in with `element.tagName`.

Next would be your hard-coded `document-body`. Seems like `document-body` is something specific to your code. Losing it would mean an infinite climb. Why not compare against `document` for a more guaranteed way to hit the top?

Here's my take on it. Not optimal, but does the same thing.

```js
function climb(element) {
  var elementName = element.id || element.tagName;
  return element === document ? [elementName] : climb(element.parentNode).concat(elementName);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(climb(e.target).join(' <- '));
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="test">test</a>
```

Comment: 1. Since you are suggesting tagName, can I assume textnodes etc will never be returned from a clickevent? 2. Will node.id ever return something other than a stringvalue? 3. Would you recommend against the use of node.id's as a node fingerprint? 4. Can you explain what happens in your climb function, is a return before a ternary op with a reference to the func itself really a good idea?

Comment: @Puddingboy **1.** I'm not sure. Ask on StackOverflow. **2.** I'm not sure (it appears it does, even when assigning `id` an object using JS). Ask on StackOverflow. **3.** Not really, but not all elements have ids by default. You need something to put in its place. **4.** It's not returning a function. It's a recursive call. Both branches of the ternary return arrays (`[elementName]` and result of `concat`).

Comment: Is there a need or grand benefit to returning the id in array form? Is this not one of the cases where not using a ternary would be better to keep it readable, assuming I still intend to extend on it? While it may sound like it, I am not asking with an intend to critique. I was just wondering.

Comment: @Puddingboy Nope. Just an alternate way to do it.